# Authorization header included despite CORS

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, google-chrome, cors, access-control

I have a really decent understanding of CORS and how it works. Some of the things I know pretty well from resolving past CORS errors and reading the spec are below:

1. By default, the browser omits credentials(`Authorization` header, cookies) from cross-origin requests(fetch `credentials:omit`)
2. If you want to include credentials in such requests, then you have to send requests with `credentials:include`
3. The server must set `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` to `true`
4. The server must not set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` and other headers to a wildcard (`*`) value when credentials are allowed

I decided to set up a hello-world react and spring boot app to play around with the CORS spec in chrome(`Version 114.0.5735.198 (Official Build) (arm64)`).

The spring boot backend running on `localhost:8080` has only a single controller, without any other setup that would manipulate the surprising results I'm about to share:

```java
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", allowedHeaders = {"authorization"})
public class CorsController {
    @GetMapping("/api/cors")
    public String testCors(){
        return "Cors success!!!";
    }
}
```

The react app(running on `localhost:3000`) has just a single effect that sends a `GET` request to the backend:

```js
import React from 'react';

function App() {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://localhost:8080/api/cors", {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "Authorization":"Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ=="
      },
    }).then((response) => {
      return response.text();
    })
    .then((text) => {
      console.log(text);
    }
    ).catch(err => {
      console.log("CORS Error caught", err);
    })
    });
  return (<></>);
}

export default App;
```

**What is going well(expectations met per CORS spec):**

Preflight request sent before my GET request because of the presence of `Authorization` header. The
`OPTIONS` request:

```
OPTIONS /api/cors HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Host: localhost:8080
Origin: http://localhost:3000
Pragma: no-cache
Referer: http://localhost:3000/
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
x-zoom-app-context: xxxx
x-zoom-app-device-nonce: xxx
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200
Vary: Origin
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: authorization
Access-Control-Max-Age: 1800
Allow: GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, PATCH
Content-Length: 0
Date: Sun, 16 Jul 2023 09:31:19 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=60
Connection: keep-alive
```

I understand the extra CORS headers because, by default, spring boot starts with an allow all setup when you apply the `@CrossOrigin` annotation **BESIDES** the `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` response header which is restrictive by default. Further, it would still not be permitted to set it to true in my settings due to the `*` for allowed origins.

**What is not going well:**

The `Authorization` header is sent in the actual request. I expected the browser to know this is a credential and omit it:

[image: Chrome network tab showing auth header sent in request]

**Fetch mode `mode:no-cors`** - I tried this in the request and the results are as expected. The response becomes opaque to my react app and also the `Authorization` header is removed from the request. Which confirms to me that there's no chance the browser does not understand that `Authorization` header is a credential. Unfortunately, it compounds my confusion:

[image: Chrome network tab showing auth header omitted in mode:no-cors]

**Explicit `credentials:omit`** - when I add this in the react fetch request, nothing changes. I understand this because indeed `omit` is the default mode.

At this point, It would seem the browser is sleeping on job.

**Explicit `credentials:include`** - With this fetch setting, from my perspective now, the browser seems to have woken up. After a successful preflight request, the request is blocked with an error I know and expect:

[image: Console error showing Actual request blocked due to wildcard header]

**Change `ACAO` header from `*` to `localhost:3000`** -  After this change, again, the request is blocked but due to the credentials setting on the server as expected:

[image: Console error showing Actual request blocked due to allow credential setting in the preflight response]

I fixed this quickly by setting `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` to `true`.

Everything working perfectly at this point.

**Can someone explain to me why the `Authorization` header was not omitted in default CORS mode by the browser as expected?**

AT THIS POINT THE BROWSER IS BEHAVING LIKE A POLICE THAT **ONLY** ARRESTS OFFENDERS THAT REPORT THEMSELVES, BECAUSE I DIDN'T NEED TO ALLOW CREDENTIALS FIRST TO SEND THEM THROUGH.

Comment: There's a difference between browser-managed credentials and client-managed credentials. Here, it's your client that's including an `Authorization` header in the request. The browser is not going to prevent the client from doing so, regardless of the `credentials` mode.

Comment: If the client (rather than the browser) is responsible for including credentials to a request, a cross-origin attacker has no way (without other vulnerabilities like cross-site scripting) of forcing his/her victim to send authenticated requests.

Comment: As for your experiment with `no-cors` mode: `no-cors` implies that the client is only allowed to include so-called [CORS-safelisted request headers](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-safelisted-request-header). `Authorization` isn't such a header, and the browser silently ignores attempts to include it in a `no-cors` request.

Comment: `credentials:omit` only applies to cookies not the authrization header. Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/credentials

Comment: @Toerktumlare No; Basic Auth, among other things, is also covered by a request's credentials mode. I can understand how MDN Web Docs' wording can lead you to believe otherwise, but the Fetch standard is the source of truth about this: https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-request-credentials-mode

Comment: @jub0bs i looked at the docs but i cant find anywhere what fetch defines as a `credential`

Comment: @Toerktumlare See https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#credentials

Comment: @jub0bs the docs are still quite unclear. Cookies and TLS certificates is clear but `authentication entry` that is defined by `tuples of username, password, and realm, used for HTTP authentication` an authentication header is not defined as a tuple. Basic authentication is base64 encoded colon separated username and password. A baerer token is not a tuple etc. So the docs are to me not very clear here

Comment: @Toerktumlare On that we can agree. Among other things, I wish the the Fetch standard clarified which types of authentication entries are meant to be managed by the browser.

Comment: thanks @jub0bs for your insights about browser vs client managed creds and also clarifying the difference in level of risk between the 2. It's enlightening to know the `Authorization` header was omitted only on account of it not being a CORS-safelisted header and not because it's a cred header. These have greatly reduced my confusion.

Comment: One key takeaway for me is that client managed creds are not in scope for the CORS credential spec. If this is correct then your statement `Basic Auth, among other things, is also covered by a request's credentials mode` looks like a contradiction. Could you give an example of how any CORS credential config affects client-managed creds(esp `Authorization` header)? From what I see it's only `Access-Control-Allowed-Headers` affecting it, which has nothing to do with credentials

Comment: Correction: I've mentioned `credentials:omit` as the default fetch credential mode, but I've noticed from the links that it's infact `credentials:same-origin`.